# jq prints help when piping output

Tags: json, bash

JQ 1.5.3 prints help when I try to pipe output:

```
$ export ZK=x
$ echo '{"jvm":{"value":"x"}}'  | jq -c --arg ZK="$ZK" 'select(.jvm.value | contains("$ZK"))' | tail -n 1
jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5]
Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]

    ...
```

But this behaviour happens only when I used `--arg` option. It does not happen when I use hardcoded values:

```
$  echo '{"jvm":{"value":"x"}}'  | jq -c 'select(.jvm.value | contains("x"))' | tail -n 1
{"jvm":{"value":"x"}}
```

It does not happen also when using `--arg` option without piping output, i.e., printing to a standard output:

```
$  echo '{"jvm":{"value":"x"}}'  | jq -c --arg ZK="$ZK" 'select(.jvm.value | contains("$ZK"))'
{"jvm":{"value":"x"}}
```

I have read about [similar issue on GitHub](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1110#issuecomment-193504718), but their workaround did not help.

```
echo '{"jvm":{"value":"x"}}'  | jq -c --arg ZK="$ZK" 'select(.jvm.value | contains("$ZK"))' | jq . -M | tail -n 1
```

How can I pipe output of jq tool?

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `--arg ZK "$ZK"`?

Comment: @Biffen you're right. Thanks.

Comment: @dzieciou Your error only occurs because `jq` only requires an explicit filter if its standard output is not the terminal. Otherwise, `jq` assumes a filter of `.`.